# Display different content with mouse events with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display content of one element when the mouse enters a box then hide it when the mouse leaves, and do the same (but with different content) when the mouse enters/leaves a separate box.  I have it working but I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing it, any help would be great.

```
<body>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="content">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <div class="text1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam animi adipisci vitae repudiandae, iure modi ut facilis eligendi quia consectetur, saepe veniam voluptates debitis consequatur placeat! Quam laudantium velit dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam animi adipisci vitae repudiandae, iure modi ut facilis eligendi quia consectetur, saepe veniam voluptates debitis consequatur placeat! Quam laudantium velit dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the javascript

```js
var txt1 = document.querySelector('.text1');
var box1 = document.querySelector('.box1');
var txt2 = document.querySelector('.text2');
var box2 = document.querySelector('.box2');

box1.addEventListener('mouseenter', showTxt);
box1.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideTxt);
box2.addEventListener('mouseenter', showTxt2);
box2.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideTxt2);

function showTxt() {
    txt1.style.display = 'block';
};

function hideTxt() {
    txt1.style.display = 'none';
};

function showTxt2() {
    txt2.style.display = 'block';
};

function hideTxt2() {
    txt2.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: why you dont use jquery for that kind of stuff ?

Comment: I'm trying to improve and get a better understanding of vanilla javascript.

Comment: you could make a function with parameter and call it to change the style or listen to an event , always try to avoid using global variable

Comment: There's a million ways to do this and to improve upon what you have. You could go for concision, reusability, performance... Do you have a particular  type of improvement  in mind when you say "cleaner"?

Comment: This question is really off-topic for Stack Overflow. You are basically asking for folks opinions on what *might* be a "better" way to accomplish the same behavior. If the code is working as desired and you are looking for feedback on best practices and performance, etc, then I'd recommend deleting this question and reposting it on Code Review (make sure that it's [on-topic for their site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first).

Comment: As im using the same functions for displaying/hiding the text elements I was trying to work out a way of a single display function and a single hide functions but changing the element its effecting rather than having to write out multiple functions for each text element. Another way of looking at it is make the code scalable so more text elements and boxes could be added.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
function registerHandlers(el1, el2) {
    el1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        el2.style.display = 'block';
    });
    el1.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        el2.style.display = 'none';
    });
}

registerHandlers(document.querySelector('.text1'), document.querySelector('.box1'));
registerHandlers(document.querySelector('.text2'), document.querySelector('.box2'));
```

also if your html structure is different and the elements are next to each other or descedents, you can do this without js with css only and the `:hover` selector.